# Why do I keep having to reenter the SIM code after each iOS update?

Tags: iphone, sim

With my iPhone 5, I've been finding that I keep having to unlock the SIM code every time I update the iOS from one minor release to the next. While this isn't a problem, as I've memorized the code, it is rather annoying.

Is there any way to change this behavior, so that I don't have to keep worrying about this?

Comment: It is just the way it is :) the Update automatically locks the SIM, since that is the "normal" condition. Just imagine what would happen if updates would unlock the SIM without asking you!

Answer (score 6):

Is this a 'SIM PIN'?  If so, go to settings - phone - SIM PIN and turn it to off.

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting to specifically avoid having to enter the SIM PIN after an update.

It is however possible to disable the PIN lock on the SIM entirely. The steps are:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Tap Cellular
3. Tap SIM Pin
4. Tap to disable SIM PIN

You will need to know the PIN in order to disable it.

Note that disabling the PIN comes with associated risks. If your SIM card or the phone with the SIM is ever stolen, a thief would be able to use your SIM card - including calling others from your phone number, ranking up your phone bill, getting SMS 2FA codes and downloading contacts that you have stored on the SIM.